# Windows 10 doesn't start UI/Explorer after scheduled update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-update

Windows asked for a time to update. When the scheduled update happened I wasn't at my computer. Now, I restarted Windows and I find that it doesn't start the UI. There's an empty screen. I can start the Task Manager
via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. 
I can start Chrome via the Task Manager and it starts without any problems, but I can't start Explorer. When I try, nothing happens.

What do I have to do to get my computer working again?

Comment: Are you sure it's not starting or perhaps it's starting and then crashing?  Have you verified by booting into a minimal configuration if Windows Explorer does not work?  After you have verified the exact behavior, you can try to uninstall the update in question to see if that helps.

Comment: You aren't using the fast ring of Windows 10 updates by any chance are you?

Comment: @Biswa : I already did this as I described.

Comment: @BennettYeo : I use the default Windows updates and haven't done anything special as far as updates are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to open the Task Manager. 
At your top-left, you should see three options (File, Options and View). 
Select “File”, click on “Run new task”, a new window should pop up:
[image: new task]

You may see “cmd” or some other value in the “Open” field.  Clear it and type “explorer”, check the “Create this task with administrative privileges” checkbox, and click “OK” or simply hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard.

Comment: OP stated that running explorer didn't work.

Comment: Try this method but with powershell/cmd: `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe` then execute `start explorer.exe`

Comment: @Antz : I already did this. Ticking the box for administrative privileges doesn't change anything.

Comment: @BennettYeo : I can start powershell. Your first command gives the answer `ERROR: The process "explorer.exe" not found`. The second answer does nothing. I tried this both directly after starting the powershell and after typing cmd in between.

Comment: cmd is not a command. I was saying you could start either powershell or cmd. Taskkill did work, it shows that your windows did not even start explorer. I was asking you to run taskkill to ensure explorer wasn't already started b/c sometimes it can have trouble starting. At this point I would recommend you boot into [safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17419/windows-7-advanced-startup-options-safe-mode). If you can boot into safe mode and explorer starts it would suggest you have something installed that is causing this problem to persist.